# What is the Jenkins FileSystem in a plugin?

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a class that passes tests fine, and runs if I invoke it in a separate Java class outside of Jenkins. It's constructor has this:

`this.fs = FileSystems.getDefault();`

Later on in execution, I added a sanity check after seeing a null pointer exception.

```
if (this.fs == null) {
  throw new Exception("No FileSystem found");
}
```

So when this plugin runs in Jenkins, the default `FileSystem` is `null` and that exception is thrown. My original code used `Paths.get` but I had switched it to `this.fs.getPath(stringPath);` so I can use DI to create a `FileSystem` for unit tests.

Using `Paths.get` had worked fine before refactor, but I'm not sure how using that method knew the correct `FileSystem`, especially given the default doesn't seem to be set in this environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `System.out`, I realized the constructor doesn't run on plugin update. It does run when saving job config. So when I saved job config, this fixed my issue via side effect. I wasn't setting `this.fs` originally, so updating the plugin didn't run those new lines. So I shouldn't be putting things into the constructor that won't be used for configuration. In hindsight this makes sense cause it's really a `@DataBoundConstructor` which implies it's being used for the data from config.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of such a problem. Sounds like your environment is badly broken, since this is defined by the Java Platform. Try bisecting—incrementally remove noncritical pieces of your plugin until you figure out which is triggering the issue.

Comment: Sounds like I'll just make a dummy plugin that runs that line, see what happens, and get back.